# Why does my C# code does not work as intended (arrays transformation, newbie)

Tags: c#, arrays, loops

I'm trying to take array of numbers (0 or 1 only) and repeatedly transform it as follows:

- first and last numbers are always 0;
- all the other numbers are
  derived from previous state of array: if array[n] and its two neighbours
  (array[n-1], array[n] and array[n+1]) have the same value (three 0s or three 1s) then newarray[n] should be be 1, otherwise it should be 0 (that produces nice patterns).

For example, if the array size is 10 and it starts with all zeroes, then program should output this:

```
0000000000
0111111110
0011111100
0001111000
0100110010
0000000000
0111111110
...and so on
```

I wrote a code that should do this and it doesn't work as intended. It always does first transformation perfectly but then begins some wrong, asymmetric, crazy stuff:

```
0000000000
0111111110
0000000000
0101010100
0000000010
0101010000
```

What makes my code behave the way it does?

Here is the code:

```
namespace test
{
    class Program
    {
        public static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            const int leng = 10; //length of array
            int[] arrayone = new int[leng]; 
            int[] arraytwo = new int[leng];
            for (int i = 0; i<=leng-1; i++)
            {
                arrayone[i] = 0;
                arraytwo[i] = 0;
            } //making two arrays and filling them with zeroes

            for (int i = 0; i<=leng-1; i++)
            {
                Console.Write(arrayone[i]);
            }
            Console.WriteLine(' '); //printing the first state of array


            for (int st=1; st<=16; st++) //my main loop
            {
                arraytwo[0]=0;
                arraytwo[leng - 1]=0; //making sure that first and last elements are zero. I'm not sure I need this since I fill both arrays with zeroes in the beginning. But it probably doesn't hurt?
                for (int i = 1; i<=leng-2; i++) //calculating new states for elements from second to second-to-last
                {
                    if (((arrayone[i-1]) + (arrayone[i]) + (arrayone[i+1]) == 0) | ((arrayone[i-1]) + (arrayone[i]) + (arrayone[i+1]) == 3) == true)
                        arraytwo[i] = 1; 
                    else 
                        arraytwo[i] = 0;
                }
                //by now arraytwo contains transformed version of arrayone

                for (int i = 0; i<=leng-1; i++)
                {
                    Console.Write(arraytwo[i]);

                } //printing result

                arrayone = arraytwo; //copying content of arraytwo to arrayone for the next round of transformation;
                Console.WriteLine(' '); 
            }



            Console.Write(" ");
            Console.ReadKey(true);
        }
    }
}
```

Tweakable version: https://dotnetfiddle.net/8htp9N

Comment: `arrayone = arraytwo` doesn't copy the _content_ of the array; they now are _the same instance_. Consider creating a new array for `arraytwo` after assigning the output to `arrayone` at the end of the loop.

Comment: You may want to indent your code properly...

Comment: Side-note: you don't need to loop the arrays to fill them with zeros, they are already initialized with zeros.

Comment: Newbie tip for you, indentation is important

Comment: What are the three neighbors?  I think you have the definition wrong.  If you are looking at the next cell (to the left) and you change the current cell then the pattern changes.  Take out a sheet of paper and write the solution down before coding so you better understand the issues.

Answer (score 3):

As pointed out you're talking an object and working on it, at the end of that you're assigning the reference not the values.  one way to combat that would be

for your line: `arrayone = arraytwo;` 
change it to : `arrayone = (int[])arraytwo.Clone();`

this will copy the values - for integers this will be sufficient.

Comment: Thanks to everyone who answered! So after first iteration my code was editing array using the same array, it explains everything. Now the code works the way I wanted it to.

Comment: For those who make come looking at this in years to come please mark this as a right answer with the big tick.

Comment: More *readable* version of `arrayone = (int[])arraytwo.Clone();` is `arrayone = arraytwo.ToArray();`

Answer (score 0):

Please, notice how your current code is *complex* and thus *diffcult to debug*. Make it simpler, *extract a method*:

```
using System.Linq;

...

private static IEnumerable<int[]> Generate(int width) {
  int[] item = new int[width];

  while (true) {
    yield return item.ToArray(); // .ToArray() - return a copy of the item

    int[] next = new int[width];

    for (int i = 1; i < item.Length - 1; ++i) 
      if (item[i - 1] == item[i] && item[i] == item[i + 1])
        next[i] = 1;

    item = next;
  }
}
```

Then you can put

```
public static void Main(string[] args) {
  var result = Generate(10) // each line of 10 items
    .Take(7) // 7 lines
    .Select(item => string.Concat(item));

  Console.Write(string.Join(Environment.NewLine, result));
}
```

Outcome:

```
0000000000
0111111110
0011111100
0001111000
0100110010
0000000000
0111111110
```